# Android layout preview stops working when adding FAB to they layout

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to use google FAB but whenever I ad FAB to my layout preview jams and stops showing changes, once I remove the FAB it starts working normally again.

I've tried to change the API version for preview as well as unchecking the select best, I tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, closing and reopening the android studio none of above worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the design library dependency, if not add this - implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0" to your app gradle and try again. Android preview won't work unless you have a successful gradle build, so look for any errors on your preview's top right corner if it's not the dependency thing.

Comment: Yes I do have the dependency in my project, I don't think there is a problem with the code, it is just the layout preview, cause when I run the applicstion on my device it works just fine and the layout just as it should be, I wanted to know why the layout preview would stop working when adding FAB? Cause it is annoying have to run the application every tike you make changes to see how the layout would look.